# Effects of two rolls for healing corruption

Tags: healing, the-one-ring, corruption

I am unsure of how healing corruption works as stated.

Page 198 bottom

> Heroes reduce their current Shadow rating attempting a
>   Craft or a Song roll with TN 14. On a successful roll, they
>   reduce their score by 2 points on a success, 4 points on a
>   great success, and 6 points on an extraordinary success
>   (Permanent Shadow points gained when suffering from a
>   bout of madness can never be healed -- see page 226).

Page 198 top

> Characters spending their Fellowship phase in a sanctuary
>   are entitled to **two rolls**, while heroes who returned home
>   are allowed a single roll instead.

When it talks about two rolls, does that mean they roll twice in craft/song and take the best result, they can roll both a craft and song, or roll two of one?

Answer (score 3):

### Heroes in a Sanctuary can make two attempts to Heal Corruption, whereas those who travel home can only make one attempt

From The One Ring (p198):

> Heroes reduce their current Shadow rating attempting **a**
> Craft or a Song **roll** with TN 14. On **a** successful **roll**, they
> reduce their [Shadow rating]

From this, it is clear that "a roll" == "an attempt". Thus, when it goes on to say (The One Ring, p198):

> Characters spending their Fellowship phase in a sanctuary
> are entitled to **two rolls**, while heroes who returned home
> are allowed a **single roll** instead.

this means that Heroes in a Sanctuary can make two "attempts", i.e. they have *two independent chances* to roll Craft **or** Song and succeed in reducing their Shadow rating.